# custom popup menu - how to?

Tags: android, popup

First off, I'm new to android development.

In our application today we have a button to choose colors. One clicks the red button and a huge dialog is shown where one can choose a color.
[image: Old behaviour]

I would like to have it like this instead:

[image: Wanted behaviour]

The colors are not just icons but circles drawn programatically on a canvas.

So my question is, how can I have a popup menu that is a bit more advanced than the regular menu/menu-items. Where should I start looking ? Is it possible to use fragments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include any view to PopupWindow element. In your case I can recommend this solution.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    popupButtonView.setOnClickListener {
        val linearLayout = LinearLayout(applicationContext)
        linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)

        for (i in 0..5) {
            linearLayout.addView(createTextView("Your text $i"))
        }

        PopupWindow(
            linearLayout,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        ).showAsDropDown(popupButtonView) 
        //Use this line, if you want change gravity
        //.showAtLocation(popupButtonView, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0) 
    }
}

private fun createTextView(tvText: String): TextView = TextView(applicationContext).apply {
    gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
    text = tvText
    compoundDrawablePadding = DRAWABLE_PADDING
    setPadding(TEXT_VIEW_PADDING)
    setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getCircleShape(), null, null, null)
}

private fun getCircleShape(): ShapeDrawable = ShapeDrawable(OvalShape()).apply {
    paint.color = getRandomColor()
    intrinsicHeight = SHAPE_SIZE
    intrinsicWidth = SHAPE_SIZE
}

private fun getRandomColor(): Int = Color.argb(255, Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256))

companion object {
    const val TEXT_VIEW_PADDING = 20
    const val DRAWABLE_PADDING = 20
    const val SHAPE_SIZE = 50
}
```

}

Comment: This seems to do what I want but my button is at the bottom and it seems like this popup window is show below my button, that is, it's hardly visible. I tried playing around with gravity(END, TOP, BOTTOM) but no luck, do you know how to get it positioned above the button ?

Comment: @ViktorEriksson, you can use .showAtLocation(popupButtonView, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0), I updated my main comment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably PopupMenu is what you need:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_example, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

Layout for popup menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_mail"
        android:title="@string/mail" />
    <item android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_upload"
        android:title="@string/upload"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:title="@string/share" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is what I meant by the regular menu/menu-items. I want more freedom to programatically draw in the popup menu/window